# Python 2.7 pip install fails missing pyconfig.h, maybe installed source distribution wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, redhat

I'm trying to upgrade to the highest release of Python 2.7 as the starting base for porting to Python 3.

On RHEL, I've successfully built the source code and created virtual environment. But when installing PIP packages it hits error saying gcc missing included file of pyconfig.h. The error happens on installation of more than one package, taking greenlet==0.4.9 as an example below.

I highly suspect it's due to the way I install Python:

- The error message says `gcc` was including directory of `-I/data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/include/python2.7`, I'm not sure whether this is related to the issue.
- When install, I changed the default `--prefix` by command `./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install --prefix=/data/python/python-2.7.16/`. Then I called `make altinstall`.
- I tested again without `--prefix` to use default, and then `make install` to install binaries to default path. This time `pip install` works OK.

Unfamiliar with source install, so not sure if I did something wrong. Please point out.

**More verbose details below if interested:**

```
(venv) [ebackenduser@setsv test-2.7.16]$ pip install greenlet==0.4.9
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting greenlet==0.4.9
  Using cached greenlet-0.4.9.tar.gz (54 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-6zrQ58
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/
  Complete output (14 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'greenlet' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o
  In file included from greenlet.h:8:0,
                   from greenlet.c:5:
  /data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
   #include "pyconfig.h"
                        ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Running setup.py clean for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
Installing collected packages: greenlet
    Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zbXvb7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/include/site/python2.7/greenlet
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/include/python2.7 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/greenlet.o
    In file included from greenlet.h:8:0,
                     from greenlet.c:5:
    /data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
     #include "pyconfig.h"
                          ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mKgh3S/greenlet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zbXvb7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/EBC/test-2.7.16/venv/include/site/python2.7/greenlet Check the logs for full command output.
(venv) [ebackenduser@setsv test-2.7.16]$
```

I tested with source code distribution of 2.7.5 and 2.7.16, both have the same error. On the same host, I have a RPM installation of Python (version 2.7.5), and that one works OK in pip install. So the issue only happens with source code installation of Python.

I'm attaching my source distribution installation steps below, for your reference.

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install --prefix=/data/python/python-2.7.16/

make altinstall

./python -m pip install --no-cache-dir virtualenv --verbose
```

Comment: are you sure you want to use Python 2? It's not officially supported anymore.

Comment: I'm in testing a upgrade path to Python-3, and hope to upgrade to the last release of 2.7 as a starting base.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install `python-devel` package, which contains headers required for compiling various Python packages

```
$ yum install python-devel
```

Comment: I just checked by `yum list installed | grep python-devel`, and it has already installed rpm **python-devel.x86_64, 2.7.5-88.el7, @rhel-7-server-rpms**.